# Turn a row's background black if cell has #VALUE! - OpenOffice Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, openoffice-calc

I'm currently playing around with formulas and made one that works perfectly for me.

Some row will get the value `#VALUE!` due to them being empty when imported and I am trying to make the whole rows background black (`#000000`) if that is the case. I can't quite find a solution for this online. What is the syntax for it?

I'll most likely set it to the whole file, so something along the lines of: `If(Cell content == #VALUE! then set this row background to black)`

Or maybe modify my command I have now to do that task directly:

`=LEFT(TRIM(Products.D2);FIND("/";TRIM(Products.D2))-1)` if output from this equals `#VALUE!` set row background to black?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: OpenOffice.org is [no longer used](https://superuser.com/tags/openoffice/info). Did you mean LibreOffice or Apache OpenOffice? Often the instructions will be the same for both but not always.

Comment: Yes, apologies, Apache Openoffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a value from an error cell, but you can use `=errortype(<cell>)` and match that to the error code you want to mark.

For instance, if you want to check cell A4 for error code 522, use `errortype(A4)=522` for conditional formatting. To find out the error code you need, just put `=errortype(A4)` in a different cell.

PS: `#VALUE` seems to be 519, see https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/ERRORTYPE

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @itsolidude I've added an example.

Comment: Thank you, |I sadly can't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Create a conditional formatting rule and use the [ISERROR](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ISERROR_function) function:

> Returns TRUE if value refers to or evaluates to any error value, including #N/A, and FALSE otherwise.

The conditional formatting rule should be a formula. For example, `=ISERROR($D1)`. It should apply to the entire table.

The images below is from Excel as I don't use OpenOffice. But the process should be close enough for you to apply them on OpenOffice.

**Caveat:** Note that the ISERROR will also return `TRUE` for other errors.

[image: Conditional Formatting rule]

**Output**

[image: Result]

Comment: It sort of works, but  some cells with no error also get marked, not quite sure why.

Comment: Maybe you selected the wrong range, or entered the wrong cell reference. See my answer for an example. Otherwise, edit the question to show the values that are unexpectedly getting marked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of @ReddyLutonadio's answer in AOO. He says that any cell will apply to the entire table in Excel, but in AOO, it is important to enter the correct cell reference.

I selected cells `A1` through `A7` and then entered `A1` in the condition, which will then relatively apply to the other cells in the selected range.

[image: start at A1]